# Autocomplete user defined function/variable names in Coda

Tags: php, autocomplete, coda

Is it possible natively, or is there a plugin, that will use Coda's autocomplete function for user defined methods and variables?

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: This is a question that is applicable to both sites. I do not understand how this is an issue. Especially one severe enough to warrant a down vote. While both sites may be a part of the exchange, they draw different sets of traffic.

Comment: [It's still not acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Jeff even writes: "*copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavor.*". As this shows a lack of research effort (not about the question's topic, but the meta stuff around asking), -1.

Comment: My mistake. I still feel a warning would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coda 2 has been released, and autocompleting user-defines functions is one of the new features.

> #### Smart Complete
>
> Autocomplete variables and functions in a document.

---

There are several mailing list posts on coda-users from over the years discussing the missing dynamic auto-completion for Coda 1.

There appears to be no way to do this really dynamically, e.g. in the same source file.

If you have finished libraries you're just reusing, [this](http://groups.google.com/group/coda-users/browse_thread/thread/c3ec5bd68eb80aa7) might help you. It's about editing the language definition bundles' code completion property list files (e.g. `Contents/Resources/ 
CodaCompletion.plist` in `/Applications/Coda.app/Contents/Resources/Modes/PHP-HTML.mode`) to add the completions you want.